# How to implicitly represent a term in FiPy that is quadratically dependent on the dependent variable

Tags: python, pde, fipy

I'm trying to model a multi-component reaction diffusion system using FiPy. Each component, \phi_i, has a diffusive term and multiple bi-molecular reaction terms (\phi_m, \phi_n). Each component's time evolution is given by the following equation:

```
\frac{d\phi_i}{dt} = D_i\nabla \phi_i + \sum_{m,n} k_{m,n}\phi_m \phi_n  ,
```

which I represent in FiPy as

```
eq = TransientTerm() ==  DiffusionTerm(D_i) + ReactionTerm
```

where

```
if i!=m and i!=n:    ReactionTerm = k_mn * \phi_m * phi_n    
elif i==m and i!=n:  ReactionTerm = ImplicitSourceTerm(k_mn * \phi_n)
elif i!=m and i==n:  ReactionTerm = ImplicitSourceTerm(k_mn * \phi_m)
```

How do I represent the ReactionTerm in the case that i==m==n? In other words, how does one represent a term quadratically dependent on the variable being solved for, as shown in the following equation:

```
\frac{d\phi_i}{dt} = \phi_i \cdot \phi_i
```

Until now, I have been representing it explicitly, but I wonder if there is a way to represent it implicitly like I do for the other terms which include the component being solved for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicitness is linear in all cases. `ImplicitSourceTerm(coeff=k_mn * phi_i)` will do.

In all cases, you need to [sweep](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/FAQ.html#iterations-timesteps-and-sweeps-oh-my) the nonlinearities, whether they come from quadratic terms in the solution variable or dependencies on other solution variables.